# Unpublish collection telescope

Tags: meteor, telescope

I'm making a website with Telescope, and I don't want to publish some information about the user.

I'm trying to make it so it won't publish `singleUser` in the [telescope users publications.](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/eccd64db2c4010f5a478f4f127079e4db7ace316/packages/telescope-users/lib/server/publications.js)

I could do this by downloading the telescope package and removing that code, but I don't want to modify the telescope source code, as recommended [here](http://docs.telescopeapp.org/docs/overview).

I couldn't find any way to unpublish a meteor collection. And when I try to make my own `Meteor.publish('singleUser', function() {});`, I get the warning `Ignoring duplicate publish named 'singleUser'`.

Any advice on how to unpublish, or undo a published collection is helpful.

Comment: I think in this case you'll have to modify the source code, sorry. But what information do you not want to publish? By default Telescope only publishes pretty standard stuff.

Comment: @Sacha Alright. I'm trying to make it so someone who isn't an admin can't see any info from the other users. So I don't want to publish the public properties that are published with `singleUser`.

Comment: Well by default very little information is published already. But you could always remove User fields and re-add them with `public: false` (although that'll probably break some stuff).